# Ubuntu Unity Start Icon Location

Tags: launcher, icons, .desktop

I have been working on an Ubuntu "Virtual Machine", kind of a virtual desktop. But I need the start icon's location, the button that sits at the top left corner. Here is an link to the site, note: you will need an account (there is a link to the desktop called "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS") http://162.213.36.242/.

Update:

- I mean the Unity Dash
- I am working on getting my domain to work (Link to my domain problem [Apache2 and Bind](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794131/apache2-and-bind))

Comment: By top left icon I presume you mean the Unity Dash, the white Ubuntu logo. That exists as PNG file.  You want the location of the PNG file  ? Or you mean something else ?

Comment: I also recommend you remove the IP address from your post for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard icon for Unity Dash is the `/usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_bfb.png` file . I don't know whether one can safely replace it, but assuming some themes have an alternative icon for the launcher, I assume it is possible.